# ByRef Argument type mismatch with Boolean

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some vba code in an Access form which produces a "ByRef Argument type mismatch" error when called under the following circumstances.

I have a small function

```
NullAndHide(ctl as control,displayitem as Boolean)
```

which works as expected when I call it like so.

```
Call NullAndHide(Me.Control,True)
```

However, if I use the following case statement to try to set the value of displayitem based on another control:

```
Dim PerPersonOption, PerRoomOption As Boolean

    Select Case PriceType_ID
Case Is = 1 'Per Person
    PerPersonOption = True
    PerRoomOption = False
Case Is = 2 'Per Room
    PerPersonOption = False
    PerRoomOption = True
End Select
```

And then

`Call NullAndHide(Me.Control,PerPersonOption)` I get the error:

ByRef Argument type mismatch

I've tested the the value of PerPersonOption with

```
msgBox PerPersonOption
```

and it returns the correct boolean value.

My function expects a Boolean, I'm giving it a Boolean - So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When declaring `Dim PerPersonOption, PerRoomOption As Boolean` only `PerRoomOption` is type of Boolean, but `PerPersonOption` is Variant.

Try to use `Dim PerPersonOption As Boolean, PerRoomOption As Boolean`

[image]

Comment: Indeed, but you're even better of just putting each variable declaration on it's own line with it's own Dim.  I've seen these Dim shortcuts go wrong so many times... it's just better to avoid it's pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks Simco! 

My understanding was that Dim x, y as z would declare both as z. I've explicitly dim'ed each option and it works as expected. Not every shortcut is a shortcut in the end, it would appear. I will follow your and Carl's advice in declaring each variable explicitly and in it's own line.

Comment: @Istari One line for each `Dim` is really not necessary, just remember to always `Dim var1 As typeA, var2 As typeB, ...`